Bind Model schema similar to binding Model database
How can I dynamically bind a schema, similar to binding a model:
db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(
    cfg_db, max_connections=8,
    stale_timeout=300,
    user=cfg_user, password=cfg_password,
    host=cfg_host, port=cfg_port
)

db.bind([BaseModel])

# How do I set the schema for base model here??


You can also use the peewee.SubclassAwareMetadata to make this process more simple, e.g.:
class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        model_metadata_class = SubclassAwareMetadata
        database = db

...

# Apply the schema to all subclasses of `Base`.
def set_schema(name):
    def _update(m):
        m._meta.schema = name
    return _update

Base._meta.map_models(set_schema('schema_name'))

Documented here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SubclassAwareMetadata
